# AWS::S3::Errors::NoSuchKey: No Such Key error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to create a method that deletes files on an S3 instance, but I am getting a `AWS::S3::Errors::NoSuchKey: No Such Key` error when I try to call `.head` or .`read` on an object.

#### app/models/file_item.rb

```
def thumbnail
    {
      exists: thumbnailable?,
      small: "http://#{bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/images/#{id}/small_thumb.png",
      large: "http://#{bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/images/#{id}/large_thumb.png"
    }
end
```

#### lib/adapters/amazons3/accessor.rb

```
module Adapters
  module AmazonS3
    class Accessor
      S3_BUCKET =  AWS::S3.new.buckets[ENV['AMAZON_BUCKET']]

      ...

      def self.delete_file(thumbnail)
        prefix_pattern = %r{http://[MY-S3-HOST]-[a-z]+.s3.amazonaws.com/}
        small_path = thumbnail[:small].sub(prefix_pattern, '')
        large_path = thumbnail[:large].sub(prefix_pattern, '')
        small = S3_BUCKET.objects[small_path]
        large = S3_BUCKET.objects[large_path]
        binding.pry
        S3_BUCKET.objects.delete([small, large])
      end
    end
  end
end
```

#### example url1

```
"http://projectname-staging.s3.amazonaws.com/images/994/small_thumb.png"
```

#### example url2

```
"http://projectname-production.s3.amazonaws.com/images/994/large_thumb.png"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming awssdk v1 for ruby.

```
small = S3_BUCKET.objects[small_path]
```

does not actually get any objects.

from: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/Bucket.html

```
bucket.objects['key'] #=> makes no request, returns an S3Object

bucket.objects.each do |obj|
  puts obj.key
end
```

so you would need to alter your code to something like:

```
to_delete = []
S3_BUCKET.objects[small_path].each do |obj|
  to_delete << obj.key
end
S3_BUCKET.objects[large_path].each do |obj|
  to_delete << obj.key
end

S3_BUCKET.objects.delete(to_delete)
```

just banged out the code, so the idea is there, you might need to correct/polish it a bit

Comment: `S3_BUCKET.objects[small_path]` doesn't appear to return a collection

Answer (score 1):

I was able to come of with a kind of different solution thanks to your answer of @Mircea above.

```
def self.delete_file(thumbnail)
  folder = thumbnail[:small].match(/(\d+)(?!.*\d)/)
  to_delete = []
  S3_BUCKET.objects.with_prefix("images/#{folder}").each do |thumb|
    to_delete << thumb.key
  end
  # binding.pry
  S3_BUCKET.objects.delete(to_delete)
end
```